# UK Plab Visa Refusal due to bank deposits even though affidavit provided for the deposit

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have successfully cleared PLAB1. My visa appointment to appear for PLAB2 was on 18 Dec 2018.
My visa was denied under section 4.2 a,c and e. My brother (he is working in the US with a reputed company) is acting as my sponsor and I have submitted supporting letters from him as well.
I work part time as a duty doctor in Bangalore with an annual salary of 250,000 INR.

For personal funds, I had shown around 250,000 INR in my bank account. 
I had transferred a sum of 100,000 INR to my bank account through a cheque from my father's account on 13 Dec 2018. **In order to explain this amount, I had attached a notarized affidavit explaining this amount as a gift from my father and mentioning that the gift is irrevocable. I had also mentioned the cheque number in the affidavit and mentioned that the amount is from my father's savings.** 
The visa officer has specifically called out the deposit of 100,000 INR in the refusal citing that we have not explained the source of these funds.[image: visa refusal]

Now my questions are,

- Do you think the visa officer overlooked the legal affidavit we had attached?
- Is there something else we can do to explain the 100,000 INR deposit apart from the affidavit?
- Should I re-apply with further explanation for the deposit?

We still have the balance in my amount and it is almost 1 month since the deposit.

Comment: Yes. The visa officer has erred. You should let them know about their mistake and hope the rectify it.

Comment: Clearly you got hosed. It’s not exactly unusual. We have some incompetent ECO’s. Reapply (or reach out to them some way) and explain and hope they do the right thing.

Comment: @David, they have clearly mentioned there is no right to appeal or right to administrative review. This seems like a standard statement. Is there anyway I can reach out to them. I don't mind re-applying as long as the visa gets approved.

Comment: @mds Thanks for the expansion; I mentioned the issue because without a full copy of the letter none of us knew for sure. The canonical SE:Travel answer to this problem is here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e In short: there's no way to reach out, and no one can guarantee that another UK visa application will be successful.

Comment: @David, thanks for replying. It really helped clear my doubts.  Any thing you suggest apart from highlighting the affidavit more in the cover letter. I had mentioned it in a paragraph but missed mentioning it in the list of documents enclosed so there is chance that the ECO might have overlooked it. Again, thanks a lot for replying.

Comment: @mds You're welcome. I would certainly list the affidavit in the list of documents; it may well be that its mention in the text was indeed skipped over. Good luck on the re-do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This isn't a duplicate. In this case, the visa officer is materially wrong in claiming "You have not submitted information to verify the origins of these large recent deposits."

Comment: @DavidRicherby So he did submit his father's bank statement? I did not see that. If he did, then it isn't a duplicate. If not, then that's the most likely reason why he was refused.

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK but the other question doesn't cover this situation in nearly enough detail to answer the question here. It just says you need to explain the source of the funds, which is exactly what the asker tried to do with the notarized letter. I don't think the other question is specific enough that we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidRicherby OK, that makes sense. Probably best to leave it open, but at least refer to that question though, as the general explanation is still useful here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That seems like the best plan to me. The question you linked is certainly helpful.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, is it necessary to include the bank statement of my father? I had not included it as he is not my sponsor. I have included bank statements from my brother for the last 6 months with the supporting letter and his payslips.

Comment: @mds Sorry but I don't know. I was discussing with Michael whether or not the site already has an answer to your question, and we concluded that it doesn't. You should still check out the link that Michael posted, since that question is relevant to your situation, but it's not the whole answer.

Comment: Wait. Your brother isn't eligible to be your sponsor, is he? The [SU07/12 Sponsorship Undertaking form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/751681/sponsorship-form.pdf) says that a sponsor must be a UK resident, but your brother is in the US. (He can promise to pay your costs but he's not within the jurisdiction of the UK courts so that promise can't be enforced.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby, are you sure about this? I know multiple people who have used sponsor outside the UK. I do have a cousin of mine who is living in the UK who is providing me an invitation letter.
Also, isn't that sponsorship form for a permanent visa. I am only applying for a 6 month visiting visa for writing my PLAB2 exam. 
"I hereby undertake that, if the sponsored person named above is granted leave to enter the UK on a permanent
basis"

Comment: @mds I'm just going by what the form says!